# Janus Demo testing

Tags: docker, janus, janus-gateway

First of all i am new to janus media server. In my recent project, i have use canyan docker image of janus. I didn't expose any port to that docker container. I hosted the container on remote server. I clone the repo https://github.com/meetecho/janus-gateway/tree/master
I am trying to check videoroom.html file. I changed my server address in settings.js file. But the problem is when i click on start video room button it shows invalid url. Can anyone provide me the documentation or any idea how i can make a video room successfully on my local host for testing purpose. Please Not I didn't use any apache or nginx on my remote server.
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

[image]

我遇到了同样的问题，[但是这个回答帮助了我](https://github.com/atyenoria/janus-webrtc-gateway-docker/issues/48#issuecomment-641657374)。
原因是我在客户端填错了路由地址。

I encountered the same issue, but [this answer helped me](https://github.com/atyenoria/janus-webrtc-gateway-docker/issues/48#issuecomment-641657374). The reason was that I had entered the wrong routing address on the client side.